# Can juju deploy charms to an EC2 instance of Windows Server?

Tags: windows, juju

Can Juju bootstrap and deploy to an EC2 cloud instance running Windows Server OS, or can Juju only boostrap/deploy to Linux instances?  I am experimenting with Juju for the first time and have installed Juju on a Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox on my local machine. I also have an EC2 Windows 2008 Server instance that I was trying to bootstrap Juju to without success.  It could be that I have a other config issues with the yaml preventing the bootstrap from working, but I first want to be sure that Juju can deploy to Windows environment before wasting more time trying to fix the bootstrap issues.

Answer (score 1):

Juju currently only deploys Ubuntu instances. On the client side, you can have an Ubuntu machine or an OSX machine. The client is Python so theoretically you can get it running on Windows, but I don't think anyone's tried that.

Even then Juju doesn't really deploy on a working instance that you already have running, it provisions a totally new instance. So you don't need to create an ubuntu instance on EC2 in order to bootstrap and deploy, Juju does all that automatically when you issue a "juju deploy" command.

I'll map this out for you by command, assuming your laptop or desktop is configured to use EC2:

```
juju bootstrap
```

This fires off an instance in EC2 to get started. You don't manually go into the AWS console or fire up an instance or install Ubuntu or anything like that, you just need to wait for AWS/Juju to do all that for you (takes about 6 minutes).

```
juju deploy mysql
```

This will fire off *another* EC2 instance; again, everything is automated, you're not launching anything ahead of time, as far as we're concerned you want mysql, so AWS/Juju will install Ubuntu server for you from the latest images (no need to specify AMI or anything), and then install and configure MySQL.

The idea behind Juju is to not have to do any of the manual things like hunting around for AMIs or going into the AWS console, you just ask what service you want and it'll snag the rest for you.

Comment: OK - So it sounds like both the machine where I'm deploying from (running the Juju client) and the machine I'm deploying to have to be Ubuntu instances.  However, I don't really understand your comment about "Juju not really deploying to a working instance", but rather "it provisions a totally new instance".  In my case, I'm using EC2... so wouldn't I first have to create a Ubuntu instance on EC2 in order to bootstrap & deploy to that instance?

Comment: Updated my answer!